# How to protect thumbnail and library images from media browser from being deleted?

Tags: 7, files, media

I have a Drupal 7 site where authenticated users can create a webpage to raise money for a charity. They can add a picture from the media library using the media browser. However, if they delete their page, this deletes the thumbnail and the library image from the db and site.

I've tried the [File Lock](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_lock) module, but that doesn't work. I've set the user permissions to where the images cannot be deleted; that doesn't work. The images are used in other places as well as the need to keep them library for future users.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this module:

[Soft delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/soft_delete)

> This module allows selected users, based on a permission, to soft
>   delete nodes. To users the operation looks like delete but the node is
>   unpublished. It's useful if you want to prevent accidental deletes or
>   bring back content that wasn't supposed to be deleted.
>
> Note that this is a very simple module, adding just a tab called
>   Delete next to View and Edit on nodes that the user can unpublish. A
>   more advanced and customizable alternative is the [Content
>   unpublish](http://drupal.org/project/content_unpublish) module.